# Grub package failed to install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have tried installing ubuntu dual with windows 10. However, at the end of the installation, ubuntu installation crashed because of failing to install grub package into /target.....

At first, I installed ubuntu 18.10 into my dell laptop. However, hereafter, I uninstalled it following the instruction from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyOBF2ePvHY.

At present, I have experimented with ubuntu 17.10, 16.04 but disppointingly encountered the same error. I'm back with my old windows 10 right now.

I would be grateful if someone could help me out, please.....

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal of Live ISO for `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I have successfully installed by just turning back to 18.10 version. However, booting into ubuntu now turns my screen off :)))

Comment: And I can't access terminal also